# Simple PHP Chat using WebSocket

Tags: javascript, php, websocket

I tested the code from website https://phppot.com/php/simple-php-chat-using-websocket/ using MAMP and it all works fine on localhost. When i tried to use this code on linux VPS server, it doesn't work when i change localhost with static ip address of my server. Besides that my server is blocking ip address and i can't access server anymore. 
I checked php extension php72-php-sockets as well as Apache module mod_proxy_wstunnel and both are turned on. I hope you understand my question, i look forward to your answer

Answer (score 0):

Contact your host provider and tell them your issue, they’ll solve it by their side.